# Can I add additional references in an existing repo?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-remote

`git clone` has the `--reference <repository>` option which sets up a sort of cache that can be used to store objects so not all need to be copied to the newly created repo.  A file `.git/objects/info/alternates` is created which lists the referenced repository directory.

I just tried and was able to specify multiple "references" while cloning and it created two lines in the `.git/objects/info/alternates` file.

My question:  Is there a command to add references in an existing repository at some point after cloning.  For example, via a command like `git remote reference <repo>`.

And, if not, is it possible to just hand-edit the `.../alternates` file to achieve the same results?

Comment: With git it's pretty much *always* possible to "just hand-edit the file".

Comment: I know it is possible to hand-edit the file.  I guess my question was whether hand-editing the file would cause any issues and accomplish what I desire.

Comment: right, and what I meant by my comment is that it works fine.